# Unable to create a discord channel on discord.py 1.7.3

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to create some commands using discord.py. I've created a command which creates a channel based on the text a user inputs using the following code:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  msg = message.content
  if msg.startswith('$new'):
    guild = discord.Guild
    await guild.create_text_channel(msg.split(' ',1)[1])
```

When a command is entered into discord this is the output:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Switch-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 30, in on_message
    if msg.startswith('$new'):
TypeError: create_text_channel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to consider the code closely. For example, what do you expect `guild = discord.Guild` to do? What would `guild = discord.Guild()` do instead, and how is that different? Do you see how that is related to the problem? (If you cannot answer questions like this, it suggests that you should follow a Python tutorial and make sure you understand the fundamentals first, before trying to use libraries like `discord.py`.) In general, [try to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) code before asking.

Comment: Before asking, it [is also a good idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to try to look up how to do things, for example [by using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=discord.py+how+to+create+a+guild).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference in Python between a class call and a method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503179/what-is-the-difference-in-python-between-a-class-call-and-a-method-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did

```py
    guild = discord.Guild
    await guild.create_text_channel(msg.split(' ',1)[1])
```

This calls an instance method from the class, so you'll have to specify the instance (`self`) that you want it to work with, which will cause the `name` argument to not be passed the way you want it to be.

See [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_text_channel#discord.Guild.create_text_channel)

What you want is to execute it from the instance:

```py
await message.guild.create_text_channel(msg.split(' ',1)[1])
# or
await discord.Guild.create_text_channel(message.guild, msg.split(' ',1)[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

you should also change

```
guild = discord.Guild
```

to

```
guild = message.guild
```